# What is the opposite of hungry?

Tags: vocabulary

Is there any adjective that means satiety? When you feel hunger you say I'm hungry, what do you say when you feel satiety? I know some people say "I'm full". But I wonder if there is a more formal alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the term `satiated`.

> He was hungry. Now he is satiated.
>
> She ate a bit off all the plates in front of her until she was satiated.

You're probably less likely to hear this in casual conversation. I think of it as being almost more of a medical term, though others can step in if that's regional.

[Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/satiety) defines the noun form, `satiety`, as:

> 1: the quality or state of being fed or gratified to or beyond capacity : surfeit, fullness
>
> 2: the revulsion or disgust caused by overindulgence or excess

Comment: what about sated instead of satiated?

Comment: I've never heard nor seen that word before, though it seems to be a synonym for satiated.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just looking for antonyms for *hungry*, you could use any of the following:

> I'm stuffed.
>
> I'm full.
>
> I'm satisfied.

Of course, there are other ways to let someone know that you're done eating, such as:

> I couldn't eat another bite.
>
> That meal was delicious.

Comment: I'm surprised to not see "sated," especially since a more formal term was requested.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, the opposite of feeling hungry would be being [**well-fed**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/well-fed):

> If you say that someone is well-fed, you mean that they get good food regularly.

Example:

> I never felt hungry when I was growing up. I was always well-fed.

Answer (score 2):

Well fed is more a description of overall condition. Eating the required amounts or more over time.

The word is either sated or satiated. Neither seen much anymore but still true.