# "that" vs. "if" in the context of indirect question

Tags: grammar

This post is derived from another one ([Is it idiomatic to say "I am not sure if I used the right ..."?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239989/109190)), where someone claims that "if" can be replaced by "**that**".

I went through a nice tutorial [*if and whether: indirect questions*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/if-or-whether) on Cambridge grammar just now and didn't find any proof that "**that**" could be used in "*indirect yes-no questions*".

I guess the substitution would be applicable for some specific situations, such as

> Actually **I am not sure if** I dealt with that problem in the right way.

However, I don't think "if" can be replaced by "**that**" in general, without affect the implication of "yes or no". For instance,

> Managers are discussing that Alice would work in Africa next year.
>
> Managers are discussing if Alice would work in Africa next year.

The meaning changes when "**that**" is substituted for "**if**".

Another example, adapted from ([What is the opposite of hungry?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/162166/109190))

> I wonder **if** there is a more formal alternative?

I guess "if" cannot be replaced by "**that**" in this kind of scenario.

Is my understanding right?

Comment: Grammatically, "that" doesn't occur in subordinate interrogatives (embedded questions). Closed interrogatives have either "if" of "whether". Semantically, there is not much difference between "not sure if" and "not sure that".

Comment: @BillJ Yes, that's what I said. I guess I didn't clarify that clearly, so I add more examples, would you please take a loot at that?